# Need help in fetching specific Objects from JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, jsp

I have a JSON array in the following format, and I need to fetch the objects that belong to the same country i.e having the same value for the "country" key or "country_short" key in my JSP. Could any one please help?

```
[{
    "country_short": "USA",
    "city": "Butler",
    "description": "",
    "date_new": "2016-09-27 21:26:23",
    "url": "--",
    "country": "United States",
    "company": "Cargill",
    "title": "Yard Driver",
    "reqid": "BUT00451",
    "state": "Wisconsin",
    "state_short": "WI",
    "location": "Butler, WI",
    "guid": "04F2182583FC429BBAEF8B86F8467A55",
    "uid": null
}, {
    "country_short": "CAN",
    "city": "Camrose",
    "description": "",
    "date_new": "2016-09-27 21:26:23",
    "url": "--",
    "country": "Canada",
    "company": "Cargill",
    "title": "Agronomy Associate",
    "reqid": "CAN00437",
    "state": "Alberta",
    "state_short": "AB",
    "location": "Camrose, AB",
    "guid": "9FB7383A512F48F893C535765F9FBE4F",
    "uid": null
}]
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JS filter method like this

a.filter(function(item){ return item.country_short.toLowerCase() == 'usa'});

Comment: Thank you.. But I am not supposed to use JS. I was able to do it using Simple JSON